# special serial number generator

Tags: python-3.x

Please, I am building an app with python and want to generate serial numbers for people that register on my app, but I don't really know how to go about it.

the serial number is supposed to be of the format 1JA002, where the first number '1' determines the function or department of the user, the first two letters are extracted from the first and the last name in that order, but the last three digits are developed based on the time you register, for instance the very first person to register will have a number '001' as his number and these digits must just be three.

Also the last three digits are also dependent on the arrangement of the letters, so if two persons have letters 'AA' from their first and last name and they were to register at the same time, the second letter from the first name is used to separate the individuals and also give them their corresponding numbers.

#   below is my code and where I got stuck!!

```
firstName='sam'   # example names 
LastName='john'
f=firstName
L=lastName
po=f[0]
ko=L[0]
firstUser='001'
def numbergen():#function to generate serial code
    count=0
    SerialNumber=''
    while True:
        if count==0:#count indicates the number time the user registered
            if (po<ko) or (po>ko) or (po==ko):
                SerialNumber+='1'+'po'+'ko'+firstUser
        count+=1
        if count==1:#serial number generation for very next user
            initialUser='002' # the very second user
```

Comment: Don't ask most of your question in bold, especially with large font.

Comment: Yeah, I am so sorry.as I am so new to this forum and this was my very first question, I had the '#' symbol on every line as I had written the question on a python script and did not know it will appear so horrible as it did. Please do not be offended

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/vernondcole/idstring for ideas.

Generally, adding meaning into a serial number (like your proposal for department plus first and last initials) is a bad idea. What happens when Juile Jones (1JJ100) gets married to Jeffry Adams (2JA100)?  Does she have to get a new number (1JA100) or does she keep her old one?  If you ignore the name change, why bother with encoding the initials in the first place? What if she changes departments, too? 2JA101?

You also must maintain the state of your serial numbers outside of your generator program. If you encode using first-and-last initials, you will need a database to keep track of all 26 squared (times number of departments) possible combinations.

Having said all that, you could get close to what you want with...

```
import idstring
department = "1"
initials = department + firstname[0] + lastname[0]
try:
  seed_value = function_to_fetch_a_seed(initials)
except someError:
  seed_value = "100"
id = idstring.IDstring(None, seed_value, initials)
print('This id =', id)
id += 1
function_to_store_your_seed(id, initials)
```

Which will meet your use case, except that the initials will follow, rather than lead, the serial portion -- and a check digit will be added.